# Using google sheets v4 api as a complex calculator api

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have a very complicated excel which contains tons of looks up and multiple complex formulae to arrive at a set of outputs.

There can be upto 10 input parameters, 100s of lookups and come up with a 100x100 grid as the output.

I want to use google sheets api over it such that I can change the inputs, read the outputs and show it to the customers.

However, if I have hundreds of customers on the website, translating to hundreds of requests to the same google sheet, all of which are reading and writing, the sheet will become inconsistent and hence useless.

What are my options? Is there a concept of session, such that the api modifies the excel only for that session and unless I do a save call, doesn't save those on the excel?

Comment: There is no such "session" concept for Google Sheets files or files held on Google Drive. In order for formulas to process, you have to write data to the spreadsheet, which means hundreds of people will be using your code to read and write to the same file at the same time, and, as you say, the sheet will become inconsistent and useless. You don't have a specific programming question (you ask for opinions on how you can move forward), so this is too broad / off-topic.

Comment: I do wonder whether a GoogleSheet, embedded in a website, with hundreds of read/write requests is going to be a very efficient and/or satisfactory solution. Perhaps it might be time to move your spreadsheet to a database so that you can serve the display and read/write requests using the database and web tools (such as jquery).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer. The following is a commercial product that I have developed. If you only want to build your own solution from scratch, then don't read any further.

I experienced the exact same issues. There was no apparent solution. I decided to dig deep. After some months, I came up with a solution. Then I decided to make the solution commercially available to make it self-sustaining.

https://SpreadsheetCalculatorAPI.com is a tool that converts a google sheets calculation into an API.

I decided to make a free plan available. Since I know you don't want to wait for permission from whoever is in charge of the money in your organization just to try out the product.

Right now, it is possible to sign up for the beta. If the feedback is positive, we will soon make it available without sign-up.

Please comment if there is anything that I forgot to mention. Then I will make sure to edit and improve this answer.

Best Regards,
Simon El Nahas